# Spree provide free shipping if user has already order in last n days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I am working on the spree application where i want the shipping cost to be 0 if there is any order by the user in past n days say 10 days. other wise apply normal delivery change say 5$.

I am planing to do it though creating using custom promotion rules.Is there are any other ways also in spree to do the same.

Comment: Your rule isn't clear to me, what do you mean by "if there is any order by the user in past n days say 10 "?? past n days from what? user created, first order, a month beginning date?

Comment: if user have any order in last 10 days

Comment: My bad, sorry. Which version of Spree are you using? Did you consider adding promotions ?

Comment: spree 2-4-stable ..yes i am creating custom promotions..

Comment: I guess custom promotion is a better way to go about it, I'd suggest add rule which accepts the number of days from which user made an order last time, and compare it with the value of last successful order's created_at of that user, which you can map with "Free shipping" action. So, all you need is to create a custom rule class.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it with customer promotion rules. There are other ways to do it, but they're really bad.

You can structure the custom rule somewhat like the [User Promotion Rule](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.4.2/core/app/models/spree/promotion/rules/user.rb) in Spree.

Just change eligible to something like:

```
order.user.orders.where('completed_at >= ?', Time.current - 10.days).any?
```